# What equivalence phrase can be substituted for "the greater effect"?

Tags: word-choice

In a technical report, I wrote: "The larger A is, **the greater effect** B has on C". Then, a native speaker suggested me do something about "the greater effect" since it's a little bit weird. However, he didn't mention any particular better equivalent.

So, which one of the following options is the best one?

- The larger A is, **the larger effect** B has on C.
- The larger A is, **the deeper effect** B has on C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything so bad about your example,
but as an alternative, you might use the verb "affect".

> The larger A is, the more that B affects C.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion as a non-native:

> The larger A is, the stronger the effect of B on C is.

You may like to remove the 'is':

> The larger A, the stronger the effect of B on C.